# SQL ORACLE add 1 second to sysdate every 10 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

In dynamic SQL, I'd like to add 1 second every 10 rows

Following query didn't work, got    "the interval is invalid"

```
select 
rownum
,(round(rownum/10,0)+1)
,sysdate + interval '(round(rownum/10,0)+1)' SECOND
from anytable_with_lots_of_rows
where rownum < 100;
```

Anyone ?  thanks !

Comment: What is "dynamic" about your SQL? Also, what do you mean by add 1 second every 10 rows? You seem to want SYSDATE + 1 second for the first ten rows, SYSDATE + 2 seconds for rows from 11 to 20, then + 3 seconds for rows 21 through 30, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

*Classic* way is the division by the number of seconds in a day, e.g.

```
with rn as (
select rownum-1 id from dual connect by level <= 100),
rn2 as (select 
id, trunc(id/10) tr_id from rn)
select 
id, tr_id,
sysdate + tr_id / (24*3600) my_date
from rn2;
```

gives

```
        ID      TR_ID MY_DATE           
---------- ---------- -------------------
         0          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         1          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         2          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         3          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         4          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         5          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         6          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         7          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         8          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
         9          0 28-06-2018 19:05:34 
        10          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        11          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        12          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        13          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        14          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        15          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        16          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        17          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35 
        18          1 28-06-2018 19:05:35
```

Alternatively, if you want to use intervals - use the function [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions108.htm#SQLRF00682)

and replace the division with the following expression

```
sysdate + NUMTODSINTERVAL(tr_id,'SECOND') my_date
```

Answer (score 0):

`interval <n> second` accepts literal numbers only, not arithmetic expressions.

However, you can do this:

```
....  + (round(rownum/10) + 1) * interval '1' second
```

or whatever formula you need to get your correct result.

Note that if you want groups of ten rows at a time, you should use "rounding up" (the function `ceil()`) and not add 1 in parentheses.