# Get Value for Last Month

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table:

```
| Month      | End Date             |
| 06/01/2019 | 07/02/2019 12:35:00  |
| 07/01/2019 | 08/03/2019 2.33.20   |
```

I want to show Start Date of next month as the very next second of End Date of Last Month.

Result:

```
| Month      | End Date             | Start Date          |
| 06/01/2019 | 07/02/2019 12:35:00  | NULL                |
| 07/01/2019 | 08/03/2019 2.33.20   | 07/02/2019 12:35:01 |
| 08/01/2019 | 09/03/2019 2.33.07   | 08/02/2019 2:33:21  |
```

....so on

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda thanks. Was just editing it.

Comment: [How to add 10 seconds in current_timestamp SQL ( Oracle )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277369/how-to-add-10-seconds-in-current-timestamp-sql-oracle) or [how to add second in oracle timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681995/how-to-add-second-in-oracle-timestamp) or [SQL ORACLE add 1 second to sysdate every 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088046/sql-oracle-add-1-second-to-sysdate-every-10-rows)

Comment: how can I know end date is 09/03/2019 2.33.07  for 08/01/2019, is it in your table too?

Comment: Yes. It's in table. I would load Month and End Date columns from a flat file. I need to start new month from the time(+1 second) where last month ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LAG` analytic function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Month, End_Date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-06-01', DATE '2019-07-02' + INTERVAL '12:35:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-08-03' + INTERVAL '02:33:20' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-08-01', DATE '2019-09-03' + INTERVAL '02:33:07' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT month,
       end_date,
       LAG( end_date ) OVER ( ORDER BY end_date ) + INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         AS start_date
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> MONTH               | END_DATE            | START_DATE         
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
> 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | 2019-07-02 12:35:00 | null               
> 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-08-03 02:33:20 | 2019-07-02 12:35:01
> 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 2019-09-03 02:33:07 | 2019-08-03 02:33:21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1545fba567517ba5df95963d0d2ec61)*

Answer (score 1):

MT0 provided the Oracle syntax already. I am not familiar with Oracle but here is SQL Server syntax I would use for this purpose, maybe useful for someone else.:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (mnt DATE, enddate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('2019-06-01','2019-07-02 12:35:00'),('2019-07-01','2019-08-03 12:35:00')

;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mnt ASC)
   FROM #temp 
)
SELECT cte.mnt,cte.enddate, startdate=DATEADD(SECOND,1,cte2.enddate) 
FROM cte 
LEFT outer JOIN cte cte2 ON cte2.rn = cte.rn-1
```

Oh, I didn't know LAG is available on SQL Server, happy to learn something new. IT also works:

```
SELECT mnt,
       enddate, 
       DATEADD(SECOND,1,LAG( enddate ) OVER ( ORDER BY enddate )) AS start_date
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: [`LAG( .... ) OVER ( ORDER BY .... )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is valid in SQL server; you don't need to use a self-join.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the query without using the analytical function. Adding different answer for the users!!

```
SELECT T1.month,
       T1.end_date,
       T2.END_DATE + INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS START_DATE
FROM   my_table t1
LEFT JOIN my_table T2 ON T2.MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(T1.MONTH,-1)
ORDER BY T1.MONTH
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7142dbccf320fd8d2a7bb7c3fb1ca0a8)

Cheers!!